# C# new operator - different between assignment to variable and without

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, object, debugging

1. What is conceptual different between creation of a new instances of a `Example` class with assignment to variables and without `new Example(); new Example();`

```cs
    public class Example
    {
    }

    Example someVariableFirst = new Example();
    Example someVariableSecond = new Example();
    //vs
    new Example();
    new Example();
```

2. How to view this in Visual Studio during app running?  Assignment to variable I'll see in `Debug->Locals`, but how to see `new Example(); new Example()`?

Comment: One creates a new `Example` and stores it in a variable, the other creates a new `Example` and then forgets all about it. You won't be able to see the `new Example()`'s you created in local variables, because you didn't store them in local variables.

Comment: `but how to see new Example()...new Example()?` Umm, assign it to a local variable like your earlier code. ;) Other than that, they are conceptually the same.

Comment: @canton7 Thank You for explanation! I catched `new Example()` instance in Debug->Locals in `this` at the time of execution.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **Why** are you asking @TimT.?

Comment: What do you mean by "How to see `new Example()`"? What do you want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Creating that object has no side effects, and the reference is never stored. So not only may it be garbage collected immediately after creation, the runtime is free to elide its creation entirely.

Comment: `the runtime is free to elide its creation entirely.` Is that true? Do you have a citation for that? I'd love to read more about that.

Comment: `So not only may it be garbage collected immediately after creation` To be fair, that is true regardless of whether you assign it to `someVariableFirst` or not.

Comment: @mjwills [I hope so, otherwise the JIT's got some explaining to do](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DC2A3utmbjnACzYCyAFAJTGnlsB2ApgO7YCiADzBQADgBtOTANysyAX3QKMlBPyGiJxOdiA). In fairness, it elides that creation even if it's assigned to a variable.

Comment: @marsze the `Example` class doesn't define any constructor and the default constructor has no side effects.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the said "no side effects" it is a bit of a lazy calculation (or delayed initialization)? I mean the case when we put this `new Example()` in a condition expression, without assigning a variable. How CLR's runtime work in this context (eventually, LINQ does same work)?

Comment: @TimT. the default constructor for an empty class does nothing observable; there is no side effect of the constructor (marsze posted an answer with side effects but has since deleted it). The is no lazy calculation or anything else; it can be elided without changing the behaviour so, just like say an empty for loop or the body of an if(false), removing it is a valid optimisation.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham Thanks your for the clarification!
I will also try to visually examine my examples (cil and meta) with the help of the ILDASM application.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to know the difference between ‘Example

someVariableFirst=new Example()’ and ‘new Example()’ ,and monitor ‘new Example()’ while the

program is running.

Example someVariableFirst;

An empty variable has been declared and cannot be directly manipulated on the class.
new Example();

An Example object is created.

Example someVariableFirst = new Example();

At this time someVariableFirst holds a reference to the created object.

Sample code:

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Student student = new Student() { Name = "test1" };
                Say(student);           
                Say(new Student() { Name = "test2"});                    
            }

            static void Say(Student student) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
        public class Student
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can see the following picture.
[image]

Besides, you can select the key word by using [Watch variables with Watch windows and QuickWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019) function.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, but using Locals window (as I commented above) is better (in my case) suited to tracking creation and assignment processes during app running.